# Django Admin widgets only available to users with Staff status

Tags: django, django-admin

My website runs under Django 1.6 and I'm using the very nice Django admin two box multi-selector widget for some of my site forms.  I've just discovered, however, that the two box selector only appears in my forms for users who have staff/admin status.  Everyone else sees the not so nice one box selector that requires scrolling and holding down the control key to find select multiple items.

I don't want to give all of these users access to the entire admin site. Is there a way to fix this?  I can't seem to find where the check for admin rights is being made.  It seems like this widget is pretty popular and I don't see similar questions, so I feel like I'm missing something.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Since I still don't have any clear direction on this, I took the alternative action of adding code to assign is_staff=1 when users are given access to the forms that use the multi-select control and remove those rights when access is removed.